# Как добавить картинку во всплывающую подсказку (Hovertip)

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать чтобы при наведении на кнопку выводилась картинка и под ней текст.

Вот кусок кода:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os
from tkinter import ttk
from idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip
    
root = tk.Tk()  
root.title("Добро пожаловать в приложение PythonRu")  
root.geometry('500x200')  

tab = ttk.Notebook(root)  
tab.grid(sticky='nsew')


tab1 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
tab2 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
tab3 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
tab4 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
tab5 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
tab6 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
# tab7 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
tab8 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
tab9 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
tab10 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
# tab11 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')
# tab12 = tk.Frame(tab, bg='black')

tab.add(tab1, text='Browser  ')
tab.add(tab2, text='Сleaning  ')
tab.add(tab3, text='InfoPC  ')
tab.add(tab4, text='Editors  ')
tab.add(tab5, text='Files  ')
tab.add(tab6, text='Media  ')
# tab.add(tab7, text='Adobe')
tab.add(tab8, text='Updates  ')
tab.add(tab9, text='Adobe  ')
tab.add(tab10, text='Utilities  ')
# tab.add(tab11, text='Adobe')
# tab.add(tab12, text='Adobe')

def q():
    subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/ChromeS.exe'])

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="S", command=q, bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.035, rely=0.1, anchor="c", height=20, width=20, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="Chrome", bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.16, rely=0.1, anchor="c", height=20, width=90, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
btn1.config(command=lambda: subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/Chrome.exe']))
H = Hovertip(btn1, "tooltip text", hover_delay=100)


def w():
    subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/FirefoxS.exe']) 

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="S", command=w, bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.035, rely=0.26, anchor="c", height=20, width=20, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="Firefox", bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.16, rely=0.26, anchor="c", height=20, width=90, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
btn1.config(command=lambda: subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/Firefox.exe']))



def e():
    subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/OperaS.exe'])
    
btn1 = Button(tab1, text="S", command=e, bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.035, rely=0.42, anchor="c", height=20, width=20, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="Opera", bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.16, rely=0.42, anchor="c", height=20, width=90, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
btn1.config(command=lambda: subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/Opera.exe']))



def r():
    subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/OperaGXS.exe'])
    
btn1 = Button(tab1, text="S", command=r, bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.035, rely=0.58, anchor="c", height=20, width=20, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="Opera GX", bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.16, rely=0.58, anchor="c", height=20, width=90, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
btn1.config(command=lambda: subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/OperaGX.exe']))

def t():
    subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/VivaldiS.exe'])

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="S", command=t, bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.035, rely=0.74, anchor="c", height=20, width=20, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="Vivaldi", bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.16, rely=0.74, anchor="c", height=20, width=90, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
btn1.config(command=lambda: subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/Vivaldi.exe']))

def y():
    subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/YandexS.exe'])

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="S", command=y, bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.035, rely=0.9, anchor="c", height=20, width=20, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="Yandex", bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.16, rely=0.9, anchor="c", height=20, width=90, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
btn1.config(command=lambda: subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/Yandex.exe']))

def l():
    subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/Edges.exe'])

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="S", command=l, bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.36, rely=0.1, anchor="c", height=20, width=20, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="Edge", bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.485, rely=0.1, anchor="c", height=20, width=90, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
btn1.config(command=lambda: subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/Edge.exe']))

def z():
    subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/URANS.exe'])

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="S", command=z, bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.36, rely=0.26, anchor="c", height=20, width=20, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="URAN", bg="#98795d", fg="White")
btn1.place(relx=0.485, rely=0.26, anchor="c", height=20, width=90, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
btn1.config(command=lambda: subprocess.call(['SOURSE/BROWSER/URAN.exe']))
```

[image: Скриншот примерного результата.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим [класс Hovertip](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4d8a515d193a4c9f3844704f974ddb870d7ee383/Lib/idlelib/tooltip.py#L145) в исходниках python:

```
class Hovertip(OnHoverTooltipBase):
    "A tooltip that pops up when a mouse hovers over an anchor widget."
    def __init__(self, anchor_widget, text, hover_delay=1000):
        """Create a text tooltip with a mouse hover delay.
        anchor_widget: the widget next to which the tooltip will be shown
        hover_delay: time to delay before showing the tooltip, in milliseconds
        Note that a widget will only be shown when showtip() is called,
        e.g. after hovering over the anchor widget with the mouse for enough
        time.
        """
        super(Hovertip, self).__init__(anchor_widget, hover_delay=hover_delay)
        self.text = text

    def showcontents(self):
        label = Label(self.tipwindow, text=self.text, justify=LEFT,
                      background="#ffffe0", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=1)
        label.pack()
```

Видим, что там вставляется `Label` с указанным текстом. В `Label` можно вставить картинку (объект `PhotoImage`) через параметр `image`, но в данной реализации `Hovertip` этот параметр в `Label` не получится передать. Поэтому делаем свою реализацию `Hovertip`, в которой в `Label` будут передаваться все именованные параметры (`**kwargs`), переданные при создании объекта.

Копипастим код класса `Hovertip` и модифицируем как нам нужно (можно было бы отнаследоваться от `Hovertip`, но тут нет особого смысла наследоваться от него, т.к. первоначальный код этого класса полностью заменяется):

```
import tkinter as tk
from idlelib.tooltip import OnHoverTooltipBase


class LabelHovertip(OnHoverTooltipBase):
    def __init__(self, anchor_widget, hover_delay=1000, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(anchor_widget, hover_delay=hover_delay)
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def showcontents(self):
        label = tk.Label(
            self.tipwindow,
            justify=tk.LEFT,
            background="#ffffe0",
            relief=tk.SOLID,
            borderwidth=1,
            **self.kwargs
        )
        label.pack()


root = tk.Tk()

bt1 = tk.Button(root, text="Text tooltip")
bt1.pack()

# При передаче параметра text будет работать как стандартный Hovertip
LabelHovertip(bt1, hover_delay=100, text="tooltip text")

bt2 = tk.Button(root, text="Image tooltip")
bt2.pack()

# При передаче параметра image в Label будет вставляться указанная картинка
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="some_image.png")
LabelHovertip(bt2, hover_delay=100, image=img, highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground="gray")
# highlightthickness=2, highlightbackground="gray" - для добавления серой рамки толщиной в 2 пикселя
# (эти параметры тоже передаются в Label)

root.mainloop()
```

Скриншоты:

[image: Всплывающая подсказка с текстом]

[image: Всплывающая подсказка с картинкой]

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось !!!